# What does 'classified' mean in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Does it mean 'designated officially secret,' as Oxford says? If so, does it fit into the context?

> Whether it is one day ***classified*** or not – it is clear that there
> are downsides to using social media platforms. Research has suggested
> that young people who spend more than two hours a day on social
> networking sites are more likely to report poor mental health. If
> you’re on Instagram, there are examples aplenty of overly-filtered
> simulations of life that are supposed to be ‘aspirational’ but instead
> make many users feel like we’re having a worse life than our peers.
> It’s of little surprise that Instagram was rated as the worst social
> media platform for young people’s mental health in a UK survey. Yet
> its audience is growing – there are now over 800 million users
> worldwide.

[BBC: How much is ‘too much time’ on social media?](https://www.bbc.com/future/article/20180118-how-much-is-too-much-time-on-social-media)

Comment: Hint: there are *multiple* definitions of *classified*. Would another makemore sense in this context?

Comment: Thank you, DrMoishe. What does the first 'it' refer to in the passage?

Comment: What are the downsides to?

Comment: "It" is a dummy pronoun that substitutes for the entire clause "that there are downsides to using social media platforms". The dummy pronoun is used because the sentence is more understandable than saying "That there are downsides to using social media platforms is clear."  They are letting the reader know in advance what they are going to say about the clause that follows:  it is clear.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning is in the first sentence of the article:
"There are two established organisations which classify mental disorders..."

So the meaning is "whether it is one day classified as a mental disorder or not..."